# REVTeX 4.1 + fixltx2e + includegraphics = doesn't work?

Tags: errors, revtex

I use MacOSX Leopard and TeXShop. This piece of code works:

```
\documentclass[preprint,floatfix]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\title{empty}

\section{fixltx2e or REVTeX 4.1 problem or mine?}

\begin{figure}[htb]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{fig1.pdf}
\caption{Awesome Image}
\label{fig:awesome_image}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

But if I load `fixltx2e`, the same piece of code it DOESN'T work!

```
\documentclass[preprint,floatfix]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\title{empty}

\section{fixltx2e or REVTeX 4.1 problem or mine?}

\begin{figure}[htb]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{fig1.pdf}
\caption{Awesome Image}
\label{fig:awesome_image}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

This is the error that is produced:

```
<fig1.pdf, id=1, 61.25pt x 74.7pt> <use fig1.pdf>
No file test3.bbl.
[1{/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
\aftergroup 
l.20 \end{document}
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: The problem comes from the `\@addtocurcol` defined in `fixltx2e.sty`. Perhaps someone can detect the cause.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can compile it if you load `fixltx2e` before the class. In that case you need `\RequirePackage` since `\usepackage` cannot be used before `\documentclass`.

```
\RequirePackage{fixltx2e}
\documentclass[preprint,floatfix]{revtex4-1}
```

Comment: This receipt has helped me to solve another trouble with RevTeX+figure. `figure` did not work for me if I tried to compile my document using XeTeX or LuaTeX. A maintainer of RevTeX answered me that they do not support XeTeX/LuaTeX (sic!). It would be interesting to understand why `\RequirePackage{fixltx2e}` makes a remedy for the problem with `figure` environment in `RevTeX` class. Note that RevTeX uses its own mechanism of placing floats which evidently fails under (Xe/Lua)TeX.

Comment: @IgorKotelnikov pdfLaTeX also encounters this problem.

Comment: @Stefan Kottwitz♦ What is the reason behind incompatibility between RevTeX and fixltx2e?